# Load local javascript file in chrome for testing?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to test some JavaScript on my local computer using the Chrome browser but Chrome will not load local resources. Is there an easy work around for this?

Comment: simply testing a webpage. preview in browser. eg: <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/moment.js"></script>

Comment: Answer: Use a web server on localhost.

Comment: What if the html file is not running on a web server, and never will? In my case I need a html page that runs locally but still needs to load json files. I cannot tweak my Chrome settings because the html file should run anywhere, not just on my own machine.

Comment: @SLaks not a good answer if you're planning to eventually run it in a WebView on Android (which WILL run local resources) but need to debug bootstrapping issues locally.

Comment: Simplest solution: drag and drop your js file to the browser console and see the magic.

Answer (score 31):

If you are trying to just test the functionality of your JavaScript file: create a blank HTML file, add a link to your JS file as you would normally load a JS file from HTML, and open the HTML file in Chrome. Go to the JavaScript console. You'll be able to interact with the functionality of your JS code as usual. You wouldn't need to set up a server for this. If still not clear, here's an example:

```html
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "path/to/your/jsfile"></script>
    </head> 
</html>
```

Comment: This worked when I did ```file:///Users/someuser/dev/file.js```

Comment: I get a *lot* of weird behavior when I try this - I can't access CSS style objects, some of my event handlers don't work, I can't provide credentials for AJaX requests, ...

Comment: I agree with @Michael this is not a good approach

Answer (score 24):

You can use a light weight webserver to serve the file. 
For example,
 1. install Node 
 2. install the "http-server" (or similar) package 
 3. Run the http-server package ( "http-server -c-1") from the folder where the script file is located 
 4. Load the script from chrome console (run the following script on chrome console

```
var ele = document.createElement("script");
var scriptPath = "http://localhost:8080/{scriptfilename}.js" //verify the script path
ele.setAttribute("src",scriptPath);
document.head.appendChild(ele)
```

1. The script is now loaded the browser. You can test it from console.

Comment: That's a lot of hassle just to test a local file. Also it won't work when the file needs to run anywhere, instead of only on your own machine.

Comment: @Kokodoko - Isn't the question about loading and executing a javascript file from the local machine?

Comment: Though this is unnecessary work for the original question, this was a great solution for adding an externally hosted script (axios for making API requests in my case) to the browser console to experiment with.

Comment: Running a server was simpler for me. If Python is installed, navigate PowerShell to the directory containing the .html file, run `python3 -m http.server 8000`, then navigate Chrome to `localhost:8000/my-file.html`. No need for modifying the script, although I did need to allow JS for localhost:8000 when Chrome prompted that it had blocked it (I have JS disabled by default in Chrome).

Answer (score 20):

To load local resources in Chrome when just using your local computer and not using a webserver you need to add the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

You can have a shortcut to Chrome that allows files access and one that does not.

Create a shortcut for Chrome on the desktop, right click on shortcut, select properties. In the dialog box that opens find the target for the short cut and add the parameter after chrome.exe leaving a space

e.g. `C:\PATH TO\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

This shortcut will allow access to files without affecting any other shortcut to Chrome you have.

When you open Chrome with this shortcut it should allow local resources to be loaded using HTML5 and the filesystem API.

Comment: I just tried this, to no effect. Is there anything else that needs to be set?

Comment: Works on linux /usr/bin/chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: Not on Win10 in Powershell or Cmd: ` C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --all
ow-file-access-from-files`. In fact in Cmd it tries to open the .exe as a page for some reason...

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu. But you must totally kill all chrome processes before such chrome restart.

Answer (score 11):

For security reasons, modern browsers won't load resource from locally running HTML files (files using `file://` protocol in the address bar).

The easiest way to get a modern browser to load and run JavaScript files in local HTML files is to run a local web server.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of setting up a Node or Apache web server just to test your JavaScript, then I'd suggest you install [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

### Visual Studio Code

Visual Studio code is a source code editor for pretty much any programming language under the sun. It has built-in support for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, TypeScript, and almost any kind of language used for Web development.

#### Install Visual Studio Code

You can get the Visual Studio Code editor for your platform from https://code.visualstudio.com/. It supports Windows, Linux, and Mac. I think it also works on your Surface Pro if that's your thing.

#### Add the Live Code Extension

After installing VS Code, you can add the [Live Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) code extension using the Extension panel (Ctrl+Shift+X in Windows) in Visual Studio Code.

[Live Server Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDqyR.png)

After adding the extension, you should see a "Go Live" button in the bottom-right corner of the Visual Studio Code IDE (as shown in the above screenshot).

#### Open in Code

Open the root folder where your HTML and JavaScript files exist in Visual Studio Code and click the "Go Live" button. Optionally, you can right-click the HTML file in the Explorer (Ctrl+Shift+E) and select `Open with Live Server` from the pop-up menu that appears.

[Open with Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9pnC.png)

This should create a locally running web server and open the file or folder in your web browser. If your file paths are correct, your JavaScript files should also load and run correctly.

### Troubleshooting

If for some reason, the page doesn't load in your favorite browser, check that the address and port number are correct. If the Live Server is running, it should display the port number in the bottom-right corner of the Visual Studio IDE. Make sure the address in your browser says `http://127.0.0.1:<PORT>/index.html` where `<PORT>` has the same number as shown in the status bar in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 6):

Use Chrome browser and with the Web Server for Chrome extension, set a default folder and put your linked html/js files in there, browse to 127.0.0.1:8887 (0r whatever the port is set at) in Chrome and open the developers panel & console. You can then interact with your html/js scripts in the console.

Comment: You can get it here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en and whatever default folder you set will be your web server, handy if you dont want to have to set up Apache or anything else.

Comment: An even shorter way if you use VS Code Editor at  https://code.visualstudio.com/ is to install the Live Server extension, then you don't need anything else at all, with your project folder (can be any folder) open in VS Code just right click on the HTML file (with linked js) in the explorer and select "open with live server", and browse to localhost:5500 and you can view output in browser and use chrome/firefox console.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest workaround I have found is to use Firefox.  Not only does it work with no extra steps (drag and drop - no muss no fuss), but blackboxing works better than Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by a feature of chrome's DevTools: Snippets

1. Create a new snippets
2. Copy and paste the file you would like to execute.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the snippet

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/

Comment: I appreciate this info, but when @Sophie Su says "copy and paste the file", I think that means copy and paste the whole contents of *one* js file.  But I think the original question was about having an html file run potentially multiple js files and commands *exactly as it would* if fetched from a server, not pushing it along one file 
 or command at a time.

Answer (score 4):

### Running a simple local HTTP server

To test such examples, one needs a local webserver. One of the easiest ways to do this is offered by Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` (or `http.server`, depending on the version of Python installed.)

```py
# 1. Install Python 3 & use:
python3 -m http.server
# On windows, instead of "python3" try "python" or "py -3"

# If you installed python version 2 then use:
python -m SimpleHTTPServer

# 2. To serve a specific folder use the --directory flag:
python3 -m http.server --directory /Users/junaid/WebstormProjects

# Note: I use MacOs & I have given the absolute path to my projects folder & I was able to serve my desired folder.
```

Comment: everyone shows this. but no one has an example of what comes next programatically.  do you then use webrowser.open with the file path to your file?  or does it have to be some http path and if so, what is the relative path from the http.server?

Comment: What's your use case, can you state what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the use case is to programmatically build and launch an html.  to do this i have to start the simplehttpserver asynchronously, then open the html. what's not discussed in these solutions to how to set a web_root w/ simplehttpserver. after much experimentation i was able to figure out how to do that so that it could find that file i was copying to a 'working directory'.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution. Make sure to share with others as well.

Comment: ok, i added yet another solution - this one for folks that want to programmatically open a file after the server has been started.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8.1 add:

--allow-file-access-from-files

to the end of the target text box after the quotes.

EX:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

### setup

You will want to **serve the file from a web server**. Everything else will be quirky workarounds that might differ greatly from the final result. On the web, files are being served via web servers. You'll want to mimic that locally.

Since you're apparently (at least part-time) being a web developer, do yourself a massive favour and install `node`, if you haven't already. It comes bundled with the `npx` binary, which we'll use. Make sure you have a recent LTS version. Bonus points for using [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n), which will make it easy to stay up to date with your versions, and even switch them as you need.

### steps to take

- Inside the folder where your file is located: `npx http-server -c-1`
- You can now access the file at http://127.0.0.1:8000/filename
- Last thing to do is make the browser load the file. [Magesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748797/2072165) works well for that, but I would recommend putting that snippet into a "custom js" extension. [This one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) has served me well so far.
- With everything in place, **simply reload the page** to get an updated version
  of your local file.

Comment: where does file name have to be on the local system?

Comment: @mike01010 Anywhere, basically. Just be careful to execute the `npx` command inside the folder where your files are (e.g. your shell should have that as the current working directory). Also, the folder should be owned by your user to avoid permission conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did by creating 2 files in the **/sandbox** directory:

- First file: **sandbox.js**
- Second file: **index.html**

```js
const name = 'Karl'

console.log('This is the name: ' + name)
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "file:///Users/karl/Downloads/sandbox/sandbox.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

You can then use Chrome or any browser to inspect and debug/console your code!

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: this question comes top on google when you search for *"chrome read local css without server"*. So...

If you really want to serve a local webpage and load its CSS and JS, and you really do not have or don't want to use a http server, then don't load the scripts nor styles; inline them.

Instead of something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="somefile.css">
```

Define the style like:

```
<style>/*Here goes all the CSS file content*/</style>
```

And the same with the JavaScript files. The HTML file will be larger, but it will work.

Basically you just have to copy the file contents and paste it inline.

**You really should use a server**, but if you are forced to, you can use this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Node.js installed, you can run the command:

```
npx serve .
```

It will serve you a static site/single page application in the current directory.

[Reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to do this, I ran across the same problem.
Somehow, EDGE renders all the scripts even if they are not via HTTP, HTTPS etc...
Open the html/js file directly from the filesystem with Edge, and it will work.

Comment: Not anymore. Even when marking as "your code" nothing happens, and the files disappear from the console.

Answer (score 0):

for my use case, i need to startup a local server, create working an interactive html page, and open it for the user to be able to interact with it.  the problem was how to set the local server's web root to my temp working folder where i create these dynamic files.  this was a quick and dirty solution.

In the below code, LOCAL_WEB_DIRECTORY is essentially the root.  and i then create/copy the files i want to open in the brower to that directory + /templates

```
import webbrowser
from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

    httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(('', 8001), lambda *_: SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(*_, directory=config.LOCAL_WEB_DIR))
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever, daemon=True)
    server_thread.start()
    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:8001//templates/' + work_html)
    while True: sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why @user3133050 is voted down, that's all you need to do...

Here's the structure you need, based on your script tag's src, assuming you are trying to load `moment.js` into `index.html`:

```
/js/moment.js
/some-other-directory/index.html
```

The `../` looks "up" at the "some-other-directory" folder level, finds the `js` folder next to it, and loads the `moment.js` inside.

It sounds like your `index.html` is at root level, or nested even deeper.

If you're still struggling, create a `test.js` file **in the same location** as `index.html`, and add a `<script src="test.js"></script>` and see if that loads. If that fails, check your syntax. Tested in Chrome 46.

Comment: It was down-voted because that only works with a webserver. Modern browser prevent this using local files. It's a "security" feature...

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way I found was to copy your file contents into you browser console and hit enter. The disadvantage of this approach is that you can only debug with console.log statements.

Answer (score -3):

Look at where your html file is, the path you provided is relative not absolute. Are you sure it's placed correctly. According to the path you gave in the example above: "src="../js/moment.js" " the JS file is one level higher in hierarchy. 
So it should be placed as following:

Parent folder
     sub-folder
                html file
      js (this is a folder)
               moment.js

The double dots means the parent folder from current directory, in your case, the current directory is the location of html file.

But to make your life easier using a server will safe you troubles of doing this manually since the server directory is same all time so it's much easier.