# jquery does not work in seperate file but works when I put it in the body of my html file?

Tags: jquery

When I put jquery code in the body of my php file it works, however when I put it in a seperate file and link it then it doesnt work? any ideas?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>


  <body>

    <p>hello</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("p").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors? And your .js and .css file links should be within the head element, not after it. The code itself however, [is fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zybfvLsd/)

Comment: Yes, no errors in the console, I have now put them in the head section and still no luck.  The code is fine?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment and you'll see if you've linked everything correctly it works

Answer (score 0):

I can only just assume that your issue is that you are developing on your local machine and loading your HTML from your harddrive.

This question likely addresses your question;

> [Load local javascript file in chrome for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748630/load-local-javascript-file-in-chrome-for-testing/33508159)

What you are running into is called `sandboxing` and is that way for security reasons.  It is concerning that IE does not display the issue actually.

This [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/169139/sandboxes-explained-how-theyre-already-protecting-you-and-how-to-sandbox-any-program/) has a good explanation of the need for your browser to be sandboxed.