# Display HTML table from xml file over web browser without using any software or installation on unix

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, xml

I am a very new to HTML and javascript. Have come across many questions with regard to my problem and after struggling a lot to find a solution, I am posting this question.

**Problem statment:**

I have an xml which I am trying to convert it to HTML so that I can display it over web browser in a table format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter name="ndlkjfidm" date="dfhkryi">
    <edge name="nnn" P="ffgnp" V="0.825" T="125c">
        <seen name="seen1">
        </seen>
        <seen name="ABB">
            <mob name="adas_jk3" type="entry">
                <nod name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="!ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_LOW">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4619" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="4.63027e-10" jus="115.178" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" alt="6.75316e-10" jus="115.178" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" alt="5.04568e-14" jus="9.63935" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" alt="1.21047e-14" jus="192.973" />
                        <raw nod="VBP" trip="4.58141e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" trip="5.19549e-09" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" trip="5.49458e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" trip="6.00563e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" trip="8.94924e-11" />
                    </temp>
                </nod>
                <nod name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_HIGH">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4644" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="1.52578e-14" jus="311.073" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" alt="1.00188e-14" jus="521.709" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" alt="4.03483e-14" jus="11.1118" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" alt="1.21047e-14" jus="192.975" />
                        <raw nod="VBP" trip="4.58141e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" trip="1.29302e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" trip="4.92723e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" trip="4.91887e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" trip="8.95356e-11" />
                    </temp>
                </nod>
            </mob>
        </seen>
    </edge>
</chapter>
```

Below are the links that I have tried.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_applications.asp

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-xml-file-and-print-the-details-as-tabular-data-by-using-javascript/

Loop holes:

I can not install anything (sudo apt install apache2 etc..) or any software (xammp etc)
Because of which the javascript does not display the table.

Tried with pandas as well but do not know how to display it over web browser and the xml too is very huge ( ~1GB)

Can someone please suggest me on how to get this done using any language combinations.

1. python with HTML and javascript
2. python with json and HTML
3. HTML with javascript

Comment: Can you please explain little more. What will be the rows and columns from this XML document ? And which attributes will be the value ?

Comment: if you can install libraries, and you cant get the results you want with AJAX.
jquery is probably your best bet.
Are you using Django?

Comment: @StamatisValis I glitch is that i can not install any libraries as its not allowed. I am using python purely as of now

Comment: this link https://pythonbasics.org/webserver/ could help you to create a web server and in the do_GET you should implement xml to html conversion

Comment: to handle big table, you should use https://datatables.net/ and show data in pages. datatables is javascript tools that use json to query data to the server, so in this case you should convert data to json format, hope this help you

Comment: Why don't you just create an XSLT stylesheet and apply it to your XML? Your browser will then do the job for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve your issue (as asked), using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

xml_data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter name="ndlkjfidm" date="dfhkryi">
    <edge name="nnn" P="ffgnp" V="0.825" T="125c">
        <seen name="seen1">
        </seen>
        <seen name="ABB">
            <mob name="adas_jk3" type="entry">
                <nod name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="!ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_LOW">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4619" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="4.63027e-10" jus="115.178" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" alt="6.75316e-10" jus="115.178" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" alt="5.04568e-14" jus="9.63935" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" alt="1.21047e-14" jus="192.973" />
                        <raw nod="VBP" trip="4.58141e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" trip="5.19549e-09" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" trip="5.49458e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" trip="6.00563e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" trip="8.94924e-11" />
                    </temp>
                </nod>
                <nod name="VSS" voltage="0.000000" vector="ENXB" active_input="NA" active_ouput="ENX">
                    <temp name="ADS_DEFAULT_temp_HIGH">
                        <raw nod="VBP" alt="7.05537e-15" jus="74.4644" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" alt="1.52578e-14" jus="311.073" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" alt="1.00188e-14" jus="521.709" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" alt="4.03483e-14" jus="11.1118" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" alt="1.21047e-14" jus="192.975" />
                        <raw nod="VBP" trip="4.58141e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDC" trip="1.29302e-12" />
                        <raw nod="VDDP" trip="4.92723e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VSS" trip="4.91887e-08" />
                        <raw nod="VBN" trip="8.95356e-11" />
                    </temp>
                </nod>
            </mob>
        </seen>
    </edge>
</chapter>


'''
```

One option to read the xml would be:

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml_data)
# df
html = df.to_html()
print(html)
```

Result:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>P</th>
      <th>V</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>seen</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>nnn</td>
      <td>ffgnp</td>
      <td>0.825</td>
      <td>125c</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, you can drill down into that xml:

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml_data, xpath=".//nod")
# df
html = df.to_html()
print(html)
```

This would result in:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>voltage</th>
      <th>vector</th>
      <th>active_input</th>
      <th>active_ouput</th>
      <th>temp</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>!ENXB</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>ENX</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
      <td>ENXB</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>ENX</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or even:

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml_data, xpath=".//raw")
# df
html = df.to_html()
print(html)
```

Returning:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>nod</th>
      <th>alt</th>
      <th>jus</th>
      <th>trip</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>VBP</td>
      <td>7.055370e-15</td>
      <td>74.46190</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>VDDC</td>
      <td>4.630270e-10</td>
      <td>115.17800</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>VDDP</td>
      <td>6.753160e-10</td>
      <td>115.17800</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>5.045680e-14</td>
      <td>9.63935</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>VBN</td>
      <td>1.210470e-14</td>
      <td>192.97300</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>VBP</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>4.581410e-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>VDDC</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>5.195490e-09</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>VDDP</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>5.494580e-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>6.005630e-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>9</th>
      <td>VBN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>8.949240e-11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td>VBP</td>
      <td>7.055370e-15</td>
      <td>74.46440</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>11</th>
      <td>VDDC</td>
      <td>1.525780e-14</td>
      <td>311.07300</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12</th>
      <td>VDDP</td>
      <td>1.001880e-14</td>
      <td>521.70900</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>13</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>4.034830e-14</td>
      <td>11.11180</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>14</th>
      <td>VBN</td>
      <td>1.210470e-14</td>
      <td>192.97500</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>15</th>
      <td>VBP</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>4.581410e-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>16</th>
      <td>VDDC</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>1.293020e-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>17</th>
      <td>VDDP</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>4.927230e-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>18</th>
      <td>VSS</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>4.918870e-08</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>19</th>
      <td>VBN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>NaN</td>
      <td>8.953560e-11</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The following pandas documentation might be helpful:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html

and

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a doable, implementable goal. A very simple approach would be to view your XML as a text. First, map the element types to tags that you would like to use. Maybe the HTML-equivalent to `chapter` is `section`. `edge`, `seen`, `mob`, `nod` are maybe divs. As about the embedded structure of `temp` and `raw`, you may want to use `ul` and `li` tags, respectively.

Pattern:

- you replace `<foo` with `<bar` and `</foo>` with `</bar>`, where `foo` is your XML node type and `bar` is the HTML element type you choose to replace it with
- you wrap the `html` and `body` tags around your content

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether this a one-off, or is it something you need to automate via reading a file?

If it's a one off, online tools are great for this kind of thing. https://wtools.io/convert-xml-to-html-table seems to work fine with your data.

If you need to read the file programmatically, your second link looks like it could be a good solution. If you need to run it locally by opening the HTML file and can't install a web server, you might want to refer to this answer on allowing Chrome to read files when loading an HTML file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20764147/13186118

Comment: thanks for your response.
Trying to automate it so i cant use the online tool.
Regarding the  --allow-file-access-from-files to a web browser location is also not allowed as this will be delivered to clients and can not ask them to do these as pre-requisites.

Comment: @PythonBang I don’t think there’s going to be much you can do here without getting some kind of web hosting to deliver this product to clients (and a proper development environment, ideally), or exploring different technologies to deliver this. Delivering standalone HTML files is not really a viable solution for an application unfortunately.

Comment: Do we have a way via python ?