# Monaco editor is tuck till I open my dev tools

Tags: angular, typescript, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I have a HTML file in which I have integrated monaco editor. But initially when I load the page the editor seems to be stuck . Only when I open my dev tools the editor starts working and if I dont open my dev tools it remains stuck. Here is the HTML code I am using:

```
                        <div class="condition-label">Condition</div>
                        <ngx-monaco-editor 
                        [ngClass]="{'error-border' : errorMessage.emptyExpression}"
                        [value]="userInput.textChange" 
                        [options]="options" 
                        [(ngModel)]="userInput.textChange" 
                        (onInit)="onInit()"
                        ></ngx-monaco-editor>
                        <ngx-loading [show]="monacoLoader"></ngx-loading>
                        <div *ngIf="errorMessage?.emptyExpression" class="error-on-empty-condition"><nile-icon name="info" size="14px" color="var(--nile-colors-red-700)"></nile-icon>This field cannot be left blank</div>
                       
                    </div>
```

Here is my TS options code :

```
public options = {
        theme : 'vs',
        language : 'javascript',
        fontSize: "14px",
        wordWrap: 'on',
        lineNumbers: "on",
        minimap: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    monacoLoader = false;

    onInit(){
        this.monacoLoader = false;
    }
    logger(){
        this.monacoLoader = false;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
```

I don't understand why this happens. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and fixed it. my editor was inside a mat-drawer. when the page was loaded initially the mat-drawer was being rendered in DOM. So due to this the mat-drawer was loaded when page loaded but the editor was not loaded. when the drawer was opened the editor was frozen as mat-drawer was already loaded without the editor. So I added a *ngIf condition for the mat-drawer which renders the drawer only when I open it manually. Once this was ensured the drawer is rendered with the editor properly.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have an HTML file. The editor won't start, because [Load local javascript file in chrome for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748630/load-local-javascript-file-in-chrome-for-testing) requires opening the dev tools console. Browsers behave this way to prevent malware.

If this is a problem, you can serve the file locally, as with a web server. Several solutions exist. I have used `python` and `php` web server.

```
python3 -m http.server

php -S localhost:8000
```

Then view the URL with the browser.

```
htmlview http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: But all the other things in my file seem to be getting loaded well. How is there an issue only with the editor?

Comment: The Javascript doesn't run. So it doesn't launch the editor (which depends on Javascript).

Comment: Note : my code is hosted on localhost:4200. Does it still behave the same way when site is hosted?

Comment: It can behave that way if Javascript is disabled on localhost. Or if it is loading resources with file:/// links, bypassing the server.

Comment: I just checked. neither is the JS disabled(if it was my angualar project wouldn't work) and I am not accessing any local files. i am running a server through which I am loading the files

Comment: Have you tried loading simpler versions of the editor with error handling? https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.45.0#example-creating-the-editor-editor-basic-options

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it. my editor was inside a mat-drawer. when the page was loaded initially the mat-drawer was being rendered in DOM. So due to this the mat-drawer was loaded when page loaded but the editor was not loaded. when the drawer was opened the editor was frozen as mat-drawer was already loaded without the editor. So I added a *ngIf condition for the mat-drawer which renders the drawer only when I open it manually. Once this was ensured the drawer is rendered with the editor properly.